# CSS fill remaining container width

Tags: css, flexbox, width, containers, fill

I have some specific problem with CSS. I was trying to find a solution but I couldn't find this kind of example:

```css
.container {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

.nested {
  background: red;
  width: calc(100vh - 20px);
}

.primary {
  background: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.secondary {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="primary">
    <div class="nested">
      ffffff
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondary">
    wwwwwww
  </div>
</div>
```

I've created a Fiddle with a simple version of the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/7nwxfgg5/

I want to extend the Green div to fill all of the available Blue container width, but I don't have any idea how I can do that.

**EDIT**

Removing *float: left* helped with width, but now I noticed that it doesnt work with height, please check this snippet:

```css
.container {
  background: blue;
}

.nested {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: calc(100vh - 20px);
}

.primary {
  background: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.secondary {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="primary">
    <div class="nested">
      ffffff
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondary">
    wwwwwww
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I resize green div to the same height as red?

Comment: Why don't you just drop `float: left` from `.secondary` definition? By giving this property, you force the width of container to be defined by its contents.

Comment: I agree with @raina77ow, remove the 'float' and the 'height' from the 'container'. 
https://jsfiddle.net/jadeallencook/7nwxfgg5/1/

Comment: What's the final layout supposed to be? What happens to the blue DIV?

Comment: @raina77ow Thanks, it worked!, I didn't know about this force property which you described.

Comment: @hungerstar Final layout: height/width of Red DIV "defines" size of everything other, yellow is a bit higher and green fills rest of space

Comment: @JohnDoe mock-up, please. Before/after. I know it seems straightforward to you when you type it out, but for most everyone else it's ?????

Answer (score 0):

Flex is really hand for layouts. I find float to be more trouble than it's worth so I try to avoid it. It makes building responsive layouts much easier. Here is a good resource to learn more: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.container {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  display:flex;
}

.nested {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.primary {
  background: yellow;
  flex:0 0 50%;
}

.secondary {
  background: green;
  flex:0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="primary">
    <div class="nested">
      ffffff
    </div><!-- nested -->
  </div><!-- primary -->
  
  <div class="secondary">
    wwwwwww
  </div><!-- secondary -->
  
</div><!-- container -->
```